# Deep-links redirects with hyphen don't work on android

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I have a deeplink embedded in my app with a hyphen such as https://www.myapp.com/first-page?leads_to=First_Page

It doesn't seem to work with hyphen in the "first-page" , but does work without first-page in there. Is this a known issue with deeplinks in android?

Comment: Read more at https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link

Comment: I know about the developer guide, but it doesn't say anything about hyphens